# Caching puzzle: expiring deleted models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

I need to expire the cache of a parent model after update, but if the update removes the parent association, the parent won't be found, so the cache isn't expired. watdo &___&

This is actually [freedrull](https://stackoverflow.com/users/173635/freedrull)'s question so he will add any clarification.

Comment: Can you give more information? (e.g. What language/framework are you using? What have you tried? ...)

Comment: i'm using rails, expiring the fragment cache with after_update calls in a sweeper.

Comment: i guess i could just use before_update, does that exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after_update would indeed be what you need, though it's possible that the associationa rea alredy gone then too.
I'd suggest testing this assumption by creating an after_update that just does a puts on the deleted association. If you can still fetch it - then fine. use that to clear the cache fragments.

otherwise I'd suggest a kind of "around" callback, a bit hacky, but should get you what you need:

in the before_update callback, save an @variable for your associations, then check if they've changed in the after_update

```
before_update :save_associations
after_update :expire_old_associations
def save_associations
   @associations_to_check = self.widgets
end
def expire_old_associations
   diff = @associations_to_check - self.widgets
   expire_fragments_for(diff) if diff.present?
end
```

See the available callbacks here:

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Callbacks

Comment: No models are actually being destroyed however, simply an association is being removed. Maybe I can use notify_observer somehow? Or do I need to set the :dependent attribute on my model?

Comment: Ah, I misread what you were asking. 

dependant is also to do with what happens when you destroy, so it's useful, but not what you need. I'll edit my answre appropriately.